# JPOS ISORequestListener: How to set custom fields for a specific transaction response, all while auto-responding to others?

Tags: jpos

Experimenting with converting my JPOS project from just vanilla JPOS code, to using Q2 instead.

One thing I'm having trouble implementing is a custom response for certain transactions of the user's choice in ISORequestListener. Currently, my tool receives a JSON message specifying what values to send in the Acquirer request message, as well as what values the issuer is to respond with.

```
{
"messages": [
    {
    "msgName": "Transaction - 01",
    "acquirer": {
        "delay": 5,
        "out": { //send out these fields in the outgoing request
            "0": "0100",
            "2": "9999999999999999",
            "3": "000000",
            "4": "000000045000",
            "6": "000000045000",
            ...
            ...
            ...
            
        },
        "in": {}
    },
    "issuer": {
        "in": {},
        "out": { //Issuer responds with these custom fields for this specific txn, other txns 
                 //auto-respond
            "0": "0110",
            "39": "05"
        }
    }
}
]}
```

Here is my Q2 setup for the issuer:

```
<channel-adaptor name="iss-channel" class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
<channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.CSChannel"
         packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="packager-config"
        value="src/main/resources/iso4.xml" />
    <property name="host" value="10.xxx.xxx.xx" />
    <property name="port" value="9999" />
    <property name="timeout" value="300000" />
</channel>
<in>iss-channel-send</in>
<out>iss-channel-receive</out>
<reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor>

<mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="iss-mux" realm="acq-realm">
<in>iss-channel-receive</in>
<out>iss-channel-send</out>
<ready>iss-channel.ready</ready>
<request-listener class="AutoResponder"></request-listener>
</mux>
```

And the AutoResponder ISORequestLister class:

```
    import org.jpos.core.Configurable;
import org.jpos.core.Configuration;
import org.jpos.core.ConfigurationException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISORequestListener;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOSource;

public class AutoResponder implements ISORequestListener, Configurable {
    private Configuration cfg;

    @Override
    public void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg) throws ConfigurationException {
        this.cfg = cfg;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(ISOSource source, ISOMsg m) {
        try {
            ISOMsg r = (ISOMsg) m.clone();
            r.setResponseMTI();
            r.set(39, cfg.get("rc", "00"));
            source.send(r);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not process message");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This current setup is fantastic for autoresponding to all transactions, but I'd like to be able to modify some of the issuer responses according to what the user would like to respond with (This is for negative tests in QA environment)

**How can I tell the ISORequestListener that I would like to send a custom field for a specific transaction, all while auto-responding to all other transactions?**

In my current tool's code, I have two threads (one for Acq, one for Iss) that build each request/response and then send it using BaseChannel.send(). But I'm unsure on how this can be achieved using Q2's ISORequestListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Let autoresponder only respond to some message types

For the first part of the question, you can add properties to your `ISORequestListener` saying which MITs you want to autorespond, or if the logic is more complex, you can add it to the `AutoResponder.process` method.

Here is a simple example, based on your code:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean process(ISOSource source, ISOMsg m) {
        try {
            if (cfg.get("handled-mtis").indexOf(m.getMTI()) {
                ISOMsg r = (ISOMsg) m.clone();
                r.setResponseMTI();
                r.set(39, cfg.get("rc", "00"));
                source.send(r);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not process message");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This would work with a configuration like this:

```xml
<request-listener class="AutoResponder">
  <property name="handled-mtis" value="0800"/>
</request-listener>
```

If you rather want to specify the not handled list, just negate the if condition, and name the property accordingly.

This works because the mux will try every request listener until one returns true. So if the auto responder returns false because it doesn't process the message's MTI, the next, in which you'll add the logic to handle the others.

## Adding custom logic to jPOS for setting other fields

Regarding the second part of your question, I'd suggest following the first 2 tutorials in [the jPOS tutorials page](https://jpos.org/tutorials). They are written for a server receiving the requests, but essentially you just need to replace that server by your mux and channel.

You just need to add the tutorial's server `request-listener` to your `mux` configuration after the other. It would be something like this:

```xml
<mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="iss-mux" realm="acq-realm">
<in>iss-channel-receive</in>
<out>iss-channel-send</out>
<ready>iss-channel.ready</ready>
<request-listener class="AutoResponder">
  <property name="handled-mtis" value="0800"/>
</request-listener>
<request-listener class="org.jpos.iso.IncomingListener" logger="Q2"
  realm="incoming-request-listener">
  <property name="queue" value="TXNMGR" /> 
  <property name="ctx.DESTINATION" value="jPOS-AUTORESPONDER" /> 
  </request-listener>
</mux>
```

You could also implement the autoresponder logic as a transaction participant of the transaction manager. You can have an idea of how, from the `SelectDestination` participant of the second tutorial.

## Dynamically change response values

If you want response values for fields set in runtime. You could create a service that take those values from the json, and put them in a space. Then, the request listener can take those values from the space like this in the `process` method:

```java
ISOMsg responseValues = space.rdp(cfg.get("response-values-key", "response-values"); <1>
if (responseValues != null) r.merge(responseValues);
```

<1> If you don't configure the `response-values-key` in the `xml` `response-values` is used as default.

You would also need to configure the space in the request listener:

```java
Space space;
void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg) {
  ...
  space = SpaceFactory.getSpace(cfg.get("space"));
}
```

Then in the component setting the values:

```java
ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
// set desired values on message
Space space = SpaceFactory.getSpace(""); //<1>
space.out("response-values", m); //<2>
```

<1> If you pass empty string here and don't configure it in the request listener, both are going to be using the same default transient space.

<2> You can make this key (`response-values`) configurable, it should be the same as the key used to retrieve it in the request listener `process` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I read through all of the tutorials but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for. Is there a way I can let the user set certain fields in the request-listener without having to hard code them? These fields and values won't be know prior to running the tool, and are passed in by the JSON POST request. So while most transactions will be auto-responded with default values, some of them need the ability to set fields and values in real time by the user, which could be anything.

Comment: I see, I strongly suggest you to implement the logic using the transaction manager approach for that logic. Can you elaborate on how that json is received by the Q2 service?

Comment: I added some details on how you could implement what I could understand about what you need.

Comment: Thank you, the JSON request functionality is currently from my main project which doesn't utilize Q2 currently. In that project, it uses SpringBoot to receive the POST request. I'll have to implement that same functionality with Q2 if I decide to convert my project to Q2. I'll take a look at the Transaction Manager / Space functionality and will report back once I have an implementation